# python text file to rows and columns

Tags: python, rows, spreadsheet, transpose

So I have been trying at this for a while and seem to have hit a road block and would like an assist.

I have a couple text files. Without writing it all out here's an example:

```
2020
Grum Grum
Stamina: 20
Agility: 23
Strength: 20.5%
Resistances: 20-21-30

2020
Mondo Silo
Stamina: 23
Agility: 13
Strength: 10.5%
Resistances: 20-21-20
```

And so on and so forth. Some are like this every 6 lines it starts a new stats file, and some text files have it so there are every 10 lines a new stats sheet is there.

My goal is to make every time the stats sheet end, to put it into a row and columns. I think it's called transposed, in spreadsheets terminology, but idk what I'm doing wrong. Or even if that's correct to say..

As an example I'd like the file to look like this when I'm done.

```
Year | Name | Stamina | Agility | Str | Res
2020 | Grum Grum | Stamina: 20 | Agility: 23 | Strength: 20.5% | Resistances: 20-21-30
```

I've tried Numpy, Pandas, and idk what I'm doing wrong and honestly don't know what to search to find the right answers.

Would appreciate it if I could get any help, these files are very big and I'd like to be able to specific which number of columns I need the stats sheet to fill.

Thank you in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this to get the dataframe desired:

```
with open(r'test1.txt','r') as file:
    data=file.read().split('\n\n')
data=[i.split('\n') for i in data]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Year','Name','Stamina','Agility','Str','Res'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Year        Name  ...              Str                    Res
0  2020   Grum Grum  ...  Strength: 20.5%  Resistances: 20-21-30
1  2020  Mondo Silo  ...  Strength: 10.5%  Resistances: 20-21-20
2  2020   Grum Grum  ...  Strength: 20.5%  Resistances: 20-21-30
3  2020  Mondo Silo  ...  Strength: 10.5%  Resistances: 20-21-20
```

And to write the dataframes of a list of `.txt` files with different number of rows, and with the same structure you can try:

### Option 1

```
import pandas as pd

files=['test1.txt','test2.txt']                     #list of files

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year','Name','Stamina','Agility','Str','Res'])  #create the dataframe

for file in files:                                  #we open each file
    with open(r'path_of_files'+file,'r') as file_r:   
        data=file_r.read().strip().split('\n\n')
        data=[i.split('\n') for i in data if i!=''] #get the rows
        print(data)
        s = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns)  
        df =pd.concat([df, s], ignore_index=True)   #we append the new rows to the dataframe
        
        
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'test3.txt', sep='|', index=False)       #write the final dataframe to the output file('test3.txt'), with '|' as separator
```

### Option 2

```
import pandas as pd

files=['test1.txt','test2.txt']                      #list of files

for file in files:                                   #we open each file
    with open(r'path_of_files'+file,'r') as file_r, open(r'test3.txt', 'a') as fout:
        data=file_r.read().strip().split('\n\n')
        data=[i.split('\n') for i in data if i!='']
        df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Year','Name','Stamina','Agility','Str','Res'])   #create a dataframe with the data of the current file
        if files.index(file)==0:
            fout.write(df.to_string( index = False)) #we let header=true to the first iteration to write the columns, and also write the data
        else:
            fout.write(df.to_string(header = False, index = False))  #we write the dataframe without the index and the columns names
        fout.write('\n')                             #a newline to place correctly the next rows
```

**EXAMPLE**
With some dummy files like the ones below(`test1.txt,test2.txt`), you can see the result(`test3.txt`) with both options:

**test1.txt**

```
2020
Grum Grum
Stamina: 20
Agility: 23
Strength: 20.5%
Resistances: 20-21-30

2020
Mondo Silo
Stamina: 23
Agility: 13
Strength: 10.5%
Resistances: 20-21-20
```

**test2.txt**

```
2020
Grum Grum
Stamina: 20
Agility: 23
Strength: 20.5%
Resistances: 20-21-30

2020
Mondo Silo
Stamina: 23
Agility: 13
Strength: 10.5%
Resistances: 20-21-20

2020
Mondo Silo
Stamina: 23
Agility: 13
Strength: 10.5%
Resistances: 20-21-20

2020
Mondo Silo
Stamina: 23
Agility: 13
Strength: 10.5%
Resistances: 20-21-20
```

**test3.txt**(Output file) ***with Option 1***

```
Year|Name|Stamina|Agility|Str|Res
2020|Grum Grum|Stamina: 20|Agility: 23|Strength: 20.5%|Resistances: 20-21-30
2020|Mondo Silo|Stamina: 23|Agility: 13|Strength: 10.5%|Resistances: 20-21-20
2020|Grum Grum|Stamina: 20|Agility: 23|Strength: 20.5%|Resistances: 20-21-30
2020|Mondo Silo|Stamina: 23|Agility: 13|Strength: 10.5%|Resistances: 20-21-20
2020|Mondo Silo|Stamina: 23|Agility: 13|Strength: 10.5%|Resistances: 20-21-20
2020|Mondo Silo|Stamina: 23|Agility: 13|Strength: 10.5%|Resistances: 20-21-20
```

**test3.txt**(Output file) ***with Option 2***

```
 Year        Name      Stamina      Agility              Str                    Res
 2020   Grum Grum  Stamina: 20  Agility: 23  Strength: 20.5%  Resistances: 20-21-30
 2020  Mondo Silo  Stamina: 23  Agility: 13  Strength: 10.5%  Resistances: 20-21-20
 2020   Grum Grum  Stamina: 20  Agility: 23  Strength: 20.5%  Resistances: 20-21-30
 2020  Mondo Silo  Stamina: 23  Agility: 13  Strength: 10.5%  Resistances: 20-21-20
 2020  Mondo Silo  Stamina: 23  Agility: 13  Strength: 10.5%  Resistances: 20-21-20
 2020  Mondo Silo  Stamina: 23  Agility: 13  Strength: 10.5%  Resistances: 20-21-20
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your examples, really appreciate the assist!

Comment: You´re welcome. I hope everything is clear, and if not, don't hesitate to ask me. :)

Answer (score 2):

- This option fixes the data format prior to loading it into a dataframe.

  - This presents the data in a standard tabular format as an option, because there are already other good answers for getting the data into the requested format.

    - Headers at the top of each column and data in each row below the header.
  - From an information storage and retrieval perspective, this is a standard way to present and store the data.
  - Storing the data in a standard way makes it easier to retrieve, and use other tools to visualize the data.
- `[0::6]`: list slicing that gets every 6th value in the list starting at 0
- `[1::6]`: list slicing that gets every 6th value in the list starting at 1
- Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to take list elements and convert them into a dictionary.
- Save the dataframe to a csv with `sep=','` or `sep='|'`
- Read the file back in with `df = pd.read_csv('characters.csv', sep='|')`

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict as dd

# read the file
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    # read the text in; results in a list of strings
    text_list = [r.strip() for r in f.readlines() if r.strip()]  # remove all new lines and empty rows

# add Year: in front of each year number
years = text_list[0::6]  # create a list of each year
text_list[0::6] = [f'Year: {f}' for f in years]

# add Name: in front of each name
names = text_list[1::6]  # create a list of each name
text_list[1::6] = [f'Name: {f}' for f in names]

# split each string at ': '
text_list = [x.split(': ') for x in text_list]

# create a dict for each value
data = dd(list)
for text in text_list:
    data[text[0]].append(text[1])

# load data into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display df
   Year        Name Stamina Agility Strength Resistances
0  2020   Grum Grum      20      23    20.5%    20-21-30
1  2020  Mondo Silo      23      13    10.5%    20-21-20

# save
df.to_csv('characters.csv', sep='|', index=False)

# file output
year|name|Stamina|Agility|Strength|Resistances
2020|Grum Grum|20|23|20.5%|20-21-30
2020|Mondo Silo|23|13|10.5%|20-21-20
```

Comment: So clean. Thank you for all of your hardwork, ty for the assist!

Comment: @strugglepy I'm happy to help anyone trying to organize their D&D characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you can read your txt file as a csv

```
file=pd.read_csv('filename.txt',sep=" ",header=None,error_bad_lines=False)

or 

file =pd.read_fwf('filename.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this. And got a tokenizing error. Error C. 
So I found a solution to this saying to error bad lines will fix it. So I wrote:

`import pandas as pd

file=pd.read_csv('stats.txt',sep=" ",error_bad_lines=False)
print(file)`

and now it says it's 83 rows x 1 columns. Anything to go on there?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line, adding each line to the output line, and writing that output line when a blank line is encountered, then you need to write one final time in case there is no final blank line at the end of the file.
I've written a small program which takes your input as `test.txt` and writes this to `test_out.txt`:

```
2020 | Grum Grum | Stamina: 20 | Agility: 23 | Strength: 20.5% | Resistances: 20-21-30
2020 | Mondo Silo | Stamina: 23 | Agility: 13 | Strength: 10.5% | Resistances: 20-21-20
```

Here is the code:

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as infile:
    with open("test_out.txt", "w") as outfile:
        columns = ""
        for line in infile:
            line = line.replace("\n", "") # remove newline from end of line
            print(line)
            if line == "" and len(columns) > 0: # if the line is a blank line, and we have columns to write, split into a new row
                outfile.write(columns + "\n")
                columns = "" # reset row
            else:
                if len(columns) > 0: # Put a seperator before every column except for the first
                    columns += " | "
                columns += line
        if len(columns) > 0: # write final row
            outfile.write(columns + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I haven't tried it yet but seeing the removal of newline \n with nothing is so smart to just make it all one line and iterate it over every nth-row.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

t = open('filepath', 'r').read()
data = [[a for a in x.split('\n') if a] for x in t.split('\n\n')]
datadf = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(datadf)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your text file in the same format with line breaks in between sets, this should work for you:

```
import xlsxwriter

items = []

# parse through .txt file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as r:
    text = list(r.read().splitlines())
    while text.count('') != 0:
        text.remove('')
    x = 0
    while True:
        items.append([])
        for num in range(0, 6):
            items[x].append(text[0])
            text.remove(text[0])
        x += 1
        if len(text) == 0:
            break
    print(items)


# Starting worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0

# Writing column titles
titles = ['Year', 'Name', 'Stamina', 'Agility', 'Str', 'Res']
for i in range(0, 6):
    worksheet.write(row, i, titles[i])

# fills in data from parsed .txt file
x, row = 0, 1
while True:
    for i in range(0, 6):
        cur = items[x][0]
        worksheet.write(row, i, cur)
        items[x].remove(cur)
    print(items)
    row += 1
    x += 1
    print('hi')
    if len(items) == x:
        break

# Closes workbook
workbook.close()
```